# Inserting new nodes while iterating through a linked list

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make an ordered linked list of tuples in VB.NET. Currently I am having issues with the sorting part. Currently, I am just iterating through when I insert a new node and Using an AddBefore or an AddAfter, but I keep getting syntax errors.

```
For node In LinkedList
    If node.Item1 < results.Item1 Then
        LinkedList.AddBefore(node, newnode)
    ElseIf node.Item1 = results.Item1 Then
        LinkedList.AddAfter(node, newnode)
    ElseIf LinkedList.Last.Equals(node) Then
        LInkedList.AddLast(results)
    End If
Next
```

It just says that there is a syntax error and when I try this:

```
For Each node In LinkedList
    If node.Item1 < results.Item1 Then
        LinkedList.AddBefore(node, newnode)
    ElseIf node.Item1 = results.Item1 Then
        LinkedList.AddAfter(node, newnode)
    ElseIf LinkedList.Last.Equals(node) Then
        LInkedList.AddLast(results)
    End If
Next
```

I get an error that the node is not the appropriate type so AddBefore and AddAfter will not work. How can I fix this problem?

The newnode is created like this:

```
newnode = New LinkedListNode(Of Tuple(Of Double, String))(results)
```

Comment: need some more code...

Comment: post definition of `AddBefore` and `AddLast`, and of what type is `node`?

Comment: it might be easier to use a SortedList or SortedDictionary, both available in System.Collections.Generic

Answer (score 1):

The `AddBefore`, `AddAfter` and `AddLast` members expect a node as the first parameter. When using `For Each` over a `LinkedList` the values are returned not the nodes.

To iterate over the nodes of a `LinkedList` you can use the `First` property to get the first node and then `Next` on each node. To get at the value of each node you must use the `Value` property:

```
    Dim node = linkedList.First
    While node IsNot Nothing
        If node.Value.Item1 < results.Item1 Then
            linkedList.AddBefore(node, newnode)
        ElseIf node.Value.Item1 = results.Item1 Then
            linkedList.AddAfter(node, newnode)
        ElseIf linkedList.Last.Equals(node) Then
            linkedList.AddLast(results)
        End If
        node = node.Next
    End While
```

Another option would be to use [System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which automatically sorts on the key.

Comment: sorry for the late response, but would it be a better idea to just create an array of these tuples and then sort them off of the first element of the tuples in the array?

Comment: if you're writing to the collection once and reading many times, then it would probably be faster to write to an array of tuples then sort. If you're continuously writing to and reading from the collection, the list may be a better option. I'd recommend profiling to see what works best for your scenario.